# How do I diffuse light that responds to the thickness of an object?

Tags: texturing, shaders, light, subsurface-scattering

I have an image of a lampshade that I am trying to make a material shader for. I have a bulb inside that is a point light or I have also used a light bulb model with emission for cycles. I am trying to render in cycles to get a photo realistic render.

I can't go with emission because I need the subsurface to stay white corresponding with the subsurface image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lampshades that are lit by an point light from the inside often benefit from some `transmission` value to allow the light to "pass" through the shade, which should respond to thickness the way you want.

Comment: Hello :). Please add some reference image, so we know what exactly you're going for.

Comment: I added a couple of images of a render and the shade I put together with translucency and sss